# Beam in roof has cracked, is this serious?

Tags: roof

Light weight beams that don't appear to do anything? (https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTPd3.jpg)[image][image][image][image]

Please can someone tell me if the beam in the photo that is cracked needs to be replaced? Can I just screw a piece of 3by2 down the inside of it to reinforce/repair? 
I just had a roofer over and he seems to think that I can do the above and that these light weight beams are not doing a lot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would replace it with a new piece of similar sized and type of material. Should be really straight forward to remove the broken one and place the new one.

Sistering a new one on against the existing one is another option if it is not possible to get at the ends of the existing member.

It is indeed possible that these play a minor role in overall structure of your house. They may have been installed at the time of the building construction to keep the ridge board in position as the rafters were cut and nailed into place. But even that said they do provide some triangulation stiffening of the roof structure in the case of horizontal stress placed on the building structure by winds.

Comment: Sorry pressed send mid way through typing.... yeah that's what I thought. I think removing will be difficult as they seem to be held in place with same bolt that holds other beams in place. You can't really see from the pic but they are only approx 15mm thick and there are two that run parallel with each other about 90mm apart. I think if I run some reinforcing wood in between the two in the existing gap and screwed through to connect the existing beams then that should be fine right?

Comment: @JamesCannon - You can probably get by doing as you propose. However my preference is to install sistered members full length if at all possible.